# Adding email attachment to Google Photos

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-photos, gmail-attachments

I am unable to locate photos in Google Photos after using the feature to save them to Google Drive from an email attachment in Gmail. It seems that the best practice is supposed to be:

- hover over the email attachment and select "Save to Drive"
- select the Google Photos folder
- select "Move"

I would think the photo should then be available in Photos, but it is nowhere to be found (yes, I was looking in the proper place chronologically based on the date taken, created date, modified date, etc.).

If I search for the photo by file name in Google Drive, I find it right where I saved it - the Google Photos folder.
The only way to get an attachment into Photos seems to be saving it to my local computer and then uploading it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How long did you wait? I've found that it takes a little while for everything to get sync'd up.

Comment: I closed this question because the Google Drive integration with Google Photos was removed several years ago.

Answer (score -1):

The Drive / Photos integration is not seamless.

You can read some details about it here: [How Google Drive works with Google Photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB&oco=0).

This doesn't address your question directly - but given that the integration is known to be troublesome, I recommend using Photos and not Drive for most actions.

Comment: Google Drive no longer syncs with Google Photos. See this blog post: https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/